# .NET - TcpClient/NetworkStream communication doesn't give full data stream but still does?

Tags: .net

I've encountered a problem regarding communication between a scanner and my program.

The intention is to scan a product by pressing a button and holding a carton with an EAN13 code beneath it, the code is then sent to my program with a Chr(13) ending character.

While making the porogram I just used another program to simulate TCP/IP connection to a scanner, and it all works fine but when I try to receive data from the scanner at the intended location I only get the first character of the string, and the rest is dropped, or well, if I manually search for the characters above the readdata length I can see them for some reason.

**The only time the program works as intended is if I quickly double press the button that activates the scanner, if so I can sometimes get a good read in my program.**

Now some might say to look over the scanner but that's not going to work. The customer have a bunch of production lines with scanners on all of them, they are currently running against a visual basic program that can get the scanner data without a problem (that program is using a TCP/IP drag&drop object in VB).

So the question is if I'm doing something stupid with the communication. An example of a code that's sent from the scanner is:

7310865690708[CR]

(CR being Chr(13) then). What's weird for me is that I'm clearly given the readbyte length 8192, but my program gets a string of length 8205, whith the CR character at the last position. But if I try to print the string I only get the first character of the string that the scanner sends me. But if I run the mid() function at position 8193-8205 I can clearly see all the characters.

What am I doing weird? I can't listen for another loop and add the strings together since I'm given the ending character. Not sure how to receive the full string.

(the weird loop that looks for the ending character again is an old function I used before, it kinda stayed since it didn't cause any problems).

How the buffer and return data looks like when the communication works:

- Scanner buffer size- 8192 -Scanner return data length- 13

How the buffer and return data looks like when the communication fails:

- Scanner buffer size- 8192 -Scanner return data length- 16386

or

- Scanner buffer size- 8192 -Scanner return data length- 8193 (which is
  odd because I can search for items above 8192)

Code (I can't show all the code, only the scanner function):

Also sorry for all the dirty output and commented lines, I'll clean it up when It's working as intended.

```
Private Function ReadScanner(ByVal SIP As String, ByVal SPORT As Integer, ByVal ID As Integer)
    Dim tcpClient As TcpClient
    Dim netstream As NetworkStream

    Try
        'need this otherwise the threads will never be shut down unless the connection is broken

        tcpClient = New TcpClient(SIP, SPORT)
        tcpClient.ReceiveTimeout = 5000
        tcpClient.SendTimeout = 2000

        netstream = tcpClient.GetStream()

        'ScannerStatusList.Items(ID) = "Online!"
        ScannerStatusThreadList(ID) = "Online!"

        Dim bytes(tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
        Dim returndata As String = ""
        While CloseProgram = False

            netstream.Read(bytes, 0, CInt(tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize))
            Dim readbytes As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)
            returndata = returndata & readbytes
            readbytes = readbytes.Replace(vbNullChar, "")
            returndata = returndata.ToString

            REMOVEME.Text = REMOVEME.Text & " ########### -START- ########### "
            REMOVEME.Text = REMOVEME.Text & " -CHARACTER BEING WATCHED- " & Mid(returndata, 1, 1)
            REMOVEME.Text = REMOVEME.Text & " -CHARACTER IN ASCII- " & Asc(Mid(returndata, 1, 1))

            REMOVEME.Text = REMOVEME.Text & " -Return data string- " & returndata

            If Len(readbytes) <= 0 Then
                netstream.Close()
                tcpClient.Close()
                Return ""

            ElseIf returndata.Contains(Chr(13)) Then
                REMOVEME.Text = REMOVEME.Text & " -FOUND 0D CHARACTER- "
                Dim StartD As Integer = 1
                Dim EndD As Integer = 2

                For i As Integer = 0 To Len(returndata) - 1
                    If returndata(i) = Chr(13) Then
                        EndD = i + 1
                        REMOVEME.Text = REMOVEME.Text & " -Character at " & i & " = " & Mid(returndata, i, 1)
                        REMOVEME.Text = REMOVEME.Text & " - at " & i - 12 & " = " & Mid(returndata, i - 12, 1)
                        REMOVEME.Text = REMOVEME.Text & " - at " & i - 11 & " = " & Mid(returndata, i - 11, 1)
                        REMOVEME.Text = REMOVEME.Text & " - at " & i - 10 & " = " & Mid(returndata, i - 10, 1)
                        REMOVEME.Text = REMOVEME.Text & " - at " & i - 9 & " = " & Mid(returndata, i - 9, 1)
                        REMOVEME.Text = REMOVEME.Text & " - at " & i - 8 & " = " & Mid(returndata, i - 8, 1)
                        REMOVEME.Text = REMOVEME.Text & " - at " & i - 7 & " = " & Mid(returndata, i - 7, 1)
                        REMOVEME.Text = REMOVEME.Text & " - at " & i - 6 & " = " & Mid(returndata, i - 6, 1)
                        REMOVEME.Text = REMOVEME.Text & " - at " & i - 5 & " = " & Mid(returndata, i - 5, 1)
                        REMOVEME.Text = REMOVEME.Text & " - at " & i - 4 & " = " & Mid(returndata, i - 4, 1)
                        REMOVEME.Text = REMOVEME.Text & " - at " & i - 3 & " = " & Mid(returndata, i - 3, 1)
                        REMOVEME.Text = REMOVEME.Text & " - at " & i - 2 & " = " & Mid(returndata, i - 2, 1)
                        REMOVEME.Text = REMOVEME.Text & " - at " & i - 1 & " = " & Mid(returndata, i - 1, 1)
                        REMOVEME.Text = REMOVEME.Text & " - at " & i & " = " & Mid(returndata, i, 1)
                    End If
                Next
                REMOVEME.Text = REMOVEME.Text & " -MID DATA- " & Mid(returndata, StartD, 13) & " - Length - " & Len(Mid(returndata, StartD, 13))
                REMOVEME.Text = REMOVEME.Text & " ########### -END- ########### "

                netstream.Close()
                tcpClient.Close()
                'ScannerStatusList.Items(ID) = "Offline!"
                ScannerStatusThreadList(ID) = "Offline!"

                'MsgBox(returndata & vbNewLine & "Start: " & StartD & " -  End: " & EndD & vbNewLine & Mid(returndata, StartD, EndD))
                'MsgBox("string length: " & Len(returndata) & vbNewLine & "Start: " & StartD & " and forward: " & (EndD - StartD))

                Return Mid(returndata, StartD, (EndD - StartD))
            End If
        End While

    Catch ex As Exception
        'MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Try
            netstream.Close()
            tcpClient.Close()
            'ScannerStatusList.Items(ID) = "Offline!"
            ScannerStatusThreadList(ID) = "Offline!"

        Catch ex2 As Exception
            ErrorBox.Text = DateTime.Now & " - Linjeid (" & ID & ") - " & ex.Message
            'ScannerStatusList.Items(ID) = "Offline!"
            ScannerStatusThreadList(ID) = "Offline!"

            Return ""
        End Try
        ErrorBox.Text = DateTime.Now & " - Linjeid (" & ID & ") - " & ex.Message
        'ScannerStatusList.Items(ID) = "Offline!"
        ScannerStatusThreadList(ID) = "Offline!"

        Return ""
    End Try

    Return vbNull
End Function
```

Sorry in advance for the horrible output format, but it can still be understood I think.

15 scanner activations (or 16 technically since the working example is a double press). But if youi'll look at the output you can see that the 7 is always found in the end, sometimes the program can't find the ending character, but then I assume the program ends because Len(readbytes) is 0, so I didn't get any follow up data anyway. Also using mid at position 8193 (what should be 7 for me since all the following positions contains the additional data) is always empty.

- ##### -START- ###########  -CHARACTER BEING WATCHED- 7 -CHARACTER IN ASCII- 55 -Return data string- 7
- ##### -START- ###########  -CHARACTER BEING WATCHED- 7 -CHARACTER IN ASCII- 55 -Return data string- 7 -FOUND 0D CHARACTER-  -Character at 8205 = 8 - at 8193 =  - at 8194 = 3 - at 8195 = 1 - at 8196 = 0 - at 8197 = 8 - at 8198 = 6 - at 8199 = 5 - at 8200 = 6 - at

  8201 = 9 - at 8202 = 0 - at 8203 = 7 - at 8204 = 0 - at 8205 = 8 -MID
  DATA- 7 ########### -END- ###########
- ##### -START- ###########  -CHARACTER BEING WATCHED- 7 -CHARACTER IN ASCII- 55 -Return data string- 7
- ##### -START- ###########  -CHARACTER BEING WATCHED- 7 -CHARACTER IN ASCII- 55 -Return data string- 7 -FOUND 0D CHARACTER-  -Character at 8205 = 8 - at 8193 =  - at 8194 = 3 - at 8195 = 1 - at 8196 = 0 - at 8197 = 8 - at 8198 = 6 - at 8199 = 5 - at 8200 = 6 - at

  8201 = 9 - at 8202 = 0 - at 8203 = 7 - at 8204 = 0 - at 8205 = 8 -MID
  DATA- 7 ########### -END- ###########
- ##### -START- ###########  -CHARACTER BEING WATCHED- 7 -CHARACTER IN ASCII- 55 -Return data string- 7
- ##### -START- ###########  -CHARACTER BEING WATCHED- 7 -CHARACTER IN ASCII- 55 -Return data string- 7 -FOUND 0D CHARACTER-  -Character at 8205 = 8 - at 8193 =  - at 8194 = 3 - at 8195 = 1 - at 8196 = 0 - at 8197 = 8 - at 8198 = 6 - at 8199 = 5 - at 8200 = 6 - at

  8201 = 9 - at 8202 = 0 - at 8203 = 7 - at 8204 = 0 - at 8205 = 8 -MID
  DATA- 7 ########### -END- ###########
- ##### -START- ###########  -CHARACTER BEING WATCHED- 7 -CHARACTER IN ASCII- 55 -Return data string- 7
- ##### -START- ###########  -CHARACTER BEING WATCHED- 7 -CHARACTER IN ASCII- 55 -Return data string- 7 -FOUND 0D CHARACTER-  -Character at 8205 = 8 - at 8193 =  - at 8194 = 3 - at 8195 = 1 - at 8196 = 0 - at 8197 = 8 - at 8198 = 6 - at 8199 = 5 - at 8200 = 6 - at

  8201 = 9 - at 8202 = 0 - at 8203 = 7 - at 8204 = 0 - at 8205 = 8 -MID
  DATA- 7 ########### -END- ###########
- ##### -START- ###########  -CHARACTER BEING WATCHED- 7 -CHARACTER IN ASCII- 55 -Return data string- 7310865690708 7310865690708 -FOUND 0D CHARACTER-  -Character at 13 = 8 - at 1 = 7 -

  at 2 = 3 - at 3 = 1 - at 4 = 0 - at 5 = 8 - at 6 = 6 - at 7 = 5 - at
  8 = 6 - at 9 = 9 - at 10 = 0 - at 11 = 7 - at 12 = 0 - at 13 = 8
  -Character at 27 = 8 - at 15 = 7 - at 16 = 3 - at 17 = 1 - at 18 = 0 - at 19 = 8 - at 20 = 6 - at 21 = 5 - at 22 = 6 - at 23 = 9 - at 24 = 0 - at 25 = 7 - at 26 = 0 - at 27 = 8 -MID DATA- 7310865690708 -
  Length - 13 ########### -END- ###########
- ##### -START- ###########  -CHARACTER BEING WATCHED- 7 -CHARACTER IN ASCII- 55 -Return data string- 7
- ##### -START- ###########  -CHARACTER BEING WATCHED- 7 -CHARACTER IN ASCII- 55 -Return data string- 7 -FOUND 0D CHARACTER-  -Character at 8205 = 8 - at 8193 =  - at 8194 = 3 - at 8195 = 1 - at 8196 = 0 - at 8197 = 8 - at 8198 = 6 - at 8199 = 5 - at 8200 = 6 - at

  8201 = 9 - at 8202 = 0 - at 8203 = 7 - at 8204 = 0 - at 8205 = 8 -MID
  DATA- 7 ########### -END- ###########
- ##### -START- ###########  -CHARACTER BEING WATCHED- 7 -CHARACTER IN ASCII- 55 -Return data string- 7
- ##### -START- ###########  -CHARACTER BEING WATCHED- 7 -CHARACTER IN ASCII- 55 -Return data string- 7 -FOUND 0D CHARACTER-  -Character at 8205 = 8 - at 8193 =  - at 8194 = 3 - at 8195 = 1 - at 8196 = 0 - at 8197 = 8 - at 8198 = 6 - at 8199 = 5 - at 8200 = 6 - at

  8201 = 9 - at 8202 = 0 - at 8203 = 7 - at 8204 = 0 - at 8205 = 8 -MID
  DATA- 7 ########### -END- ###########
- ##### -START- ###########  -CHARACTER BEING WATCHED- 7 -CHARACTER IN ASCII- 55 -Return data string- 7310865690708  -FOUND 0D CHARACTER-  -Character at 13 = 8 - at 1 = 7 - at 2 = 3 - at 3 = 1 -

  at 4 = 0 - at 5 = 8 - at 6 = 6 - at 7 = 5 - at 8 = 6 - at 9 = 9 - at
  10 = 0 - at 11 = 7 - at 12 = 0 - at 13 = 8 -MID DATA- 7310865690708 -
  Length - 13 ########### -END- ###########
- ##### -START- ###########  -CHARACTER BEING WATCHED- 7 -CHARACTER IN ASCII- 55 -Return data string- 7310865690708  -FOUND 0D CHARACTER-  -Character at 13 = 8 - at 1 = 7 - at 2 = 3 - at 3 = 1 -

  at 4 = 0 - at 5 = 8 - at 6 = 6 - at 7 = 5 - at 8 = 6 - at 9 = 9 - at
  10 = 0 - at 11 = 7 - at 12 = 0 - at 13 = 8 -MID DATA- 7310865690708 -
  Length - 13 ########### -END- ###########

Comment: A compliant but terrible implementation of `NetworkStream.Read` could always just return one byte. You have to pay attention to the return value because that tells you *how many bytes of your buffer contain real data*. And you've got not guarantee that the number it returns is going to match the size of any buffer used during any particular `Write` call at the other end. TCP is a *stream of bytes*. Not "messages".

Comment: Ah, so instead of asking for buffer size and read from that, I'll basically just read one character at a time and add it together in my returndata?

Comment: No, use big buffers, by all means, but you need to pay attention to how much of it gets filled each time. If you're wanting messaging (so you know when you've received all of one "message"), it's up to you to do framing (e.g. first send an `int` that says how big the message is, then send the message. At the receiving end, first use a 4 bytes buffer that ~99% of the time will be filled by one call to `Read` but you still need to check and loop if required, then create a buffer big enough for the message and loop until the sum total of all `Read` return values matches the message size)

Comment: Great, will do, thanks!

Comment: Well I solved it by just puzzling everything together manually.

If they send 7310865690708Chr(13), then the 7 will be on mid(sendstring,1,1) then I have to loop til I find Character 13, then I just:

add everything together by: Fullstring = Fullstring & mid(sendstring, i, i-11), Fullstring = Fullstring & mid(sendstring, i, i-10) etc until the entire string is put together... Because I couldn't get the program to read it in as a complete string by itself for some reason.